# Adding custom elements to a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, popup, jpopupmenu, jmenuitem

The problem can be stated in two different ways:

**1.** I have a `JPopupMenu` where I want to insert a component which is not a `JMenuItem` (a custom `JTree`)... but I dont know how to do it

or

**2.** I have a different Popup (`JPopupPanel`) and I want to add `JMenuItems` below my custom `JTree` and that those `JMenuItems` work as if they were inserted in a `JPopupMenu`: they are highlighted when mouse is over and popup is closed when one of them is selected.

Any hints?

NOTE: in **2.** I can add the JMenuItems without problem, show they are shown in the Popup, but they dont act as when they are in a JMenu or JPopupMenu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1. `JPopupMenu` supports insertion of any `Component` with the method

```
public void insert(Component component, int index)
```

For 2. Did you add an ActionListener to the menu?

Comment: Was looking for something like add, but didn't see insert... thanks